# iOS - removing borders around a Round Rect button

Tags: ios, button, imagebutton

I got a simple question. I have a Round Rect button which contains an image (like ImageButton in Android). I want to remove the borders around the button, how do you do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the Type to custom in the IB window under properties.

Comment: But will it still inherit the properties of a button, like being able to click it etc?

Comment: Yes, it only affects the presentation of the control, not the behavior.

Comment: How can I do it with a bar button?